# Magento 2 Admin product catalog broken

Tags: magento2, products, product-list

A client of mine has set in the product catalog adminpage the products per page to 999. But the server is not strong enough to handle the request, due to the ajax call I can't set the dropdown back to a lower value. And the page is loading endless right now.

So my question is where is the value stored of the admin products per page setting (Database, XML) and what is the name/key of the parameter? I want to reset this value.

Comment: I'm facing same issue on a client website, did you got any solution yet?